# Laravel inner join column not found

Tags: php, laravel

I try to:

1. select categories
2. from those categories search in products `subspecifications`
3. return those `subspecifications` to select in other input

## Logic

1. Product has `category_id` column
2. product `subspecifications` will save in 3rd table named
   `product_subspecification` where in there `product_id` and
   `subspecification_id` are stored

## Code

```
public function create()
{
    //get all categories, so i can select
    $categories = Category::all();

    // find category id of chosen ones
    $categories2 = Category::all();
    foreach($categories2 as $cats){
        $catid = $cats->id;
    }

    //get subspecifications in selected categories
    $subspecifications = DB::table('product_subspecification')
        ->join('products','products.category_id', '=', $catid)
        ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
        ->get();

    $statuses = Status::all();
    return view('admin.landings.create', compact('categories', 'subspecifications', 'statuses'));
}
```

## Issue

it suppose to work like image below:

[image: screen1]

I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'on
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `product_subspecification` inner join
>   `products` on `products`.`category_id` = `3` inner join
>   `subspecifications` on `subspecifications`.`id` =
>   `product_subspecification`.`subspecification_id`)

Any idea?

## UPDATE

I've made something like:

```
public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $categories2 = Category::all();
        foreach($categories2 as $cats){
            $catid = $cats->id;
        }
        $subspecifications = DB::table('products')
                    ->where('category_id', $catid)
                    ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                    ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
                    ->groupBy('subspecifications.id')
                    ->get();
        $statuses = Status::all();
        return view('admin.landings.create', compact('categories', 'subspecifications', 'statuses'));
    }
```

it appears to be working however there is 2 issues:

1. my data are repeating, for eaxmple if i used `core i3` in 2
   categories when i select both caregories it shows `core i3` 2 times
2. I need to remove `subspecifications` if i removed their category from input 1.

Comment: It seems you had accidently put the core logic outside of foreach loop.

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati what should i do?